# Typesetting a formula

Tags: formatting

I want to input a formula like the one below:

[image]

but occasionally when I use classroom assistant in `Palettes` the formula I am still typing will become something like this

[image]

Why is that ? What should I do ?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: What happens if you select the subscript expression and execute the menu command Cell > Convert To > TraditionalForm?

Comment: Trying the `ctrl + 9` and `ctrl + 0` key

Comment: I voted to leave this open because I don't see an answer for the **"Why is that?"** part of the question.